# How Blog software such as Windows Live Writer access Blogs

Tags: windows, blogs

I am wondering How a blog software such as Windows Live writer reads/updates so many blogs such as Telligent, Wordpress, Blogger blogs.

Is there a commom web services standard exposed by these blog providers?

I have a telligent blog hosted on blogs.msdn.com and looking to access it contents in my custom web program. Any idea how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They most likely use [xml-rpc](http://www.xmlrpc.com/) to talk to the specific blog engines, I know that wordpress and blogger support this. The iPhone App certainly requires xml-rpc to update wordpress blogs outside of a web browser.